# Anatomically Correct Abysmal Locusts

Tags: fantasy-races, anatomy, anatomically-correct

The abysmal locusts are a race of creatures described in the Bible. They are the inhabitants of the abyss

As the name implies, they are locusts. However, they have some anatomical distinctions. They have the tail of a scorpion, a humanoid head, and a thoracic shell made of iron. They also have human-like intelligence and society

This description presents many issues, such as how they might invent, fly, or reproduce

**How could these creatures fit together as a functional species?**

Comment: You're sweeping a quite broad strike, and it's worse with sentience into play; Perhaps you would gain from focusing on some specific parts of it? Here's a few sample themes : Movement, crafting, social interactions...

Comment: @Tortliena This is a common way to do Anatomically Correct questions, and dividing questions only makes sense if you've got a clear bijection between problems and solutions, which isn't the case here

Comment: Not necessarily, especially since nothing in the anatomically-correct tag description or [meta-discussion](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2797/80336) tells that it needs to take the whole creature functionally. What matters more is a well written question. Sadly you either lack details to answer accurately or you're too broad to answer at all. It's like asking to calibrate a microscope using 7 sliders at the same time : You either have to move one handle at a time, or set in place 5 or 6 for us. I'd start with adding some details and references, locusts are not that famous.

Comment: Given that the Bible is readily available to many people but the verse/s referring to abysmal locusts are IMO not the best-known section, how about a reference to allow people to look at the primary source material?

Comment: For inspiration, I found one I particularly like for its looks, a *humanoid* locust https://monstersdownthepath.tumblr.com/post/616582071125770240/spiritual-spotlight-deskari-lord-of-the-locust

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 Revelation 9. There are no humanoid scorpions elsewhere in the Bible and it matches every point.

Comment: @Tortliena, he's provided the design characteristics that have been imposed on him by his source material, and is presumably trying to get as plausible an answer as possible. Nothing wrong with that, IMO. Getting realistic depictions of the strangest parts of Revelation was always going to be tricky.

Comment: Fun fact: both "abyssal" and "abysmal" can mean "of, or pertaining to an abyss", but _abysmal_ can also mean [extremely or hopelessly bad or severe](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/abysmal). Abysmal locust are presumably rubbish at swarming and devouring stuff.

Comment: @SeanOConnor If it's tricky, it can be wise to slice it and take it one step at a time, then :).

Comment: @Tortliena slicing it into several questions. As most of these creatures come to be. Sorry, please adjust. VTC.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

## Intelligence

This is easy to solve, by simply making these locusts bigger. The size of a large bird should be more than enough

## Hands

True hands probably aren't necessary. Most of its functions could be served  by the mouth and feet, especially with a few adaptations to this end

## Neck

An interesting solution here would be to have a humanoid neck and ribcage behind the head, with the ribcage set into the thorax. This should provide adequate connection between the skeletons

## Legs

While exoskeleton legs could support a bird-sized bug, iron is heavy and endoskeletons are useful. An extension of the ribcage into the thorax, with ungulate forelegs, would make an excellent basis for strong legs. The beefy handles, however, would be better served by a reptilian anatomy

## Wings

Locust wings need a chitinous exoskeleton to work, which these locusts lack. These wings could instead work as teleost-like fins. They won't be able to fly, but their wings would be less unwieldy

## Viscera

They'd likely benefit from more powerful organs. The heart and lungs could be kept in the ribcage, with other vertebrate organs in the abdomen, with the large intestine placed in the tail

## Reproduction

Scorpion reproduction looks like a good option here, as it makes more sense than the cloacal system in locusts and humans

Answer (score 2):

**Spot Repair drone**

[image]

This is not a biological animal. It is a small robotic creature. Of course people in Biblical times had never seen a machine so they gave a strange description of a metal locust in terms of things they had seen before.

The locust is designed to performs spot repairs in hard-to-reach places. The main job is to fly behind a loose panel of an aircraft or vehicle and spot weld two bits of metal together using the electronic welder attached to its tail.

The welder is the end of a long scorpion like tail, to reach into extra small nooks and crannies. It also delivers a nasty *sting* if you try to damage it.

They locusts are made of metal because machines typically are. Their face has a small view screen that works both ways -- it displays the face of the  "driver". Though the drones usually act autonomously and the face is blank.

They are smart because they are programmed to work  unsupervised.  They live in a  society with people, because they return to the base when not active. They do not invent new things but sometimes a new model with a new tool will come out and it looks like the locusts invented something new. But it was really the human engineers. They typically do not reproduce as they are mass produced at the foundry.

*Image is from the Magic the Gathering Pest Artifact Creature Token. The artist is not credited on the card.*

Answer (score 1):

Frame challenge: These are the Revelation 9 locusts, right?

Surely these are mechanical drones rather than a biological species. That eliminates the need for reproduction; Abaddon just produces more of them. It allows some of the pretty outlandish features like womens faces to be engineered in. Sentience could be just enough swarm intelligence to achieve whatever Abaddon tells them to do. In fact, the fact that they have a king (presumably not himself a locust) works really well with it. Make them the size of a recreational drone and put an 'eerie valley' lifeless plastic womans face mask on the front.

Revelation 9:5-11 NASB
And they were not permitted to kill anyone, but to torment for five months; and their torment was like the torment of a scorpion when it stings a man. [6] And in those days men will seek death and will not find it; they will long to die, and death flees from them. [7] The appearance of the locusts was like horses prepared for battle; and on their heads appeared to be crowns like gold, and their faces were like the faces of men. [8] They had hair like the hair of women, and their teeth were like the teeth of lions. [9] They had breastplates like breastplates of iron; and the sound of their wings was like the sound of chariots, of many horses rushing to battle. [10] They have tails like scorpions, and stings; and in their tails is their power to hurt men for five months.[11] They have as king over them, the angel of the abyss; his name in Hebrew is Abaddon, and in the Greek he has the name Apollyon.